# how to find css file path in magento2

Tags: magento2, css

I am working on theming part in Magento2.

Whenever I compile `.less` file, two css file is created: `styles-l.css` and `styles-m.css`. Whenever we inspect the element and try to see the CSS applied in the browser, we are not able to find the CSS file path. I mean, I cannot know from which files my CSS is coming. Is there any way to find the CSS file path?

Answer (score 2):

Css path is pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/css/.
If you clear the cache css will be affected and also don't forget the css in your layout file.

Answer (score 2):

what files are you searching for exactly? The less files are compiled into the styles-m and styles-l css files. These files are in the pub/static folder like @sabarivel said and your browser should also point you to the right location of these.

If you are searching for the source of the compiled css code, you might want to turn on client side less compilation like described here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css-preprocess.html

It will cost you some performance, but when you inspect the element, you should see the location of the less file in your browser instead of just the compiled css file.